# Open ID Access Token Translating

Tags: openid

Hello All i am new to Stackoverflow and i am facing problem in using OpenID with web apps
I am using Google OpenID selector for the user to authenticate from their own google account.I have done this succesfuly and i got the username acces token but not actual username 
.i am still unable to retrive the username and emailaddress who logged into my webpage.I want to get email with of the username and his First and Last name so that i keep in know that who is using my webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. The whole deal about OpenID is "Identification": it's only a substitute for the old-fashioned username/password fields. If you need anything else, you'll still have to ask the users.

However, some OpenID provider (not all!) implement the "[Simple Registration Extension](http://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_0.html)" (sreg). If you look at this specification, you can enable the OpenID provider to return some details about the user that is signing in, like nickname, real name and/or email address. But again: this isn't part of the OpenID specification and you shouldn't rely on this.

But you could use this information to create a user profile on your own server, when a users first signs in using OpenID. (Just like Stack Overflow does).

Comment: have u any sample code or any example to get the username or email address of logged in user

Comment: You could try by googling "openid sreg <your programming language>" ;-) It depends a lot on the programming language you're using. But if you need code samples, I'd suggest you find a library (for your programming language) which implements OpenID and sreg.